# Change of variables

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism

Given this generalized coordinates,

$$
u=r+x
$$
$$
v=r-x
$$

Can somebody explain me how can I transform this Hamiltonian

$$
H(x,y,p_{x},p_{y})=\frac{p_{x}^{2}+p_{y}^{2}}{2m}-\frac{k}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}
$$

into $H(u,v,p_{u},p_{v})$, and give an explicit expression for $H(u,v,p_{u},p_{v})$?

The goal of this exercise is to obtain the Hamilton-Jacobi equation in terms of these coordinates, $u,v$, and reduce it to quadratures.

$$
H_{Kepler}(u,v,p_{u},p_{v})=\frac{2}{m}\left( p_{u}^{2} \frac{u}{u+v}+p_{v}^{2} \frac{v}{v+u}\right)-\frac{2K}{u+v}
$$

$$
S=W_{1}(u)+W_{2}(v)-Et
$$
$$
\frac{2}{m}\left(\left(\frac{\partial W_{1}}{\partial u} \right)^{2} \frac{u}{u+v}\left(\frac{\partial W_{2}}{\partial v} \right)^{2} \frac{v}{v+u}\right)-\frac{2K}{u+v}=E
$$

$$
u\left( \left(\frac{\partial W_{1}}{\partial u} \right)^{2} -\frac{mE}{2}\right)=v\left(- \left(\frac{\partial W_{2}}{\partial v} \right)^{2} +\frac{mE}{2}\right)+km \equiv \alpha
$$

$$
\left(\frac{\partial W_{1}(u)}{\partial u} \right)=\sqrt{\frac{mE}{2}+\frac{\alpha}{u}}
$$
$$
\left(\frac{\partial W_{2}(v)}{\partial v} \right)=\sqrt{\frac{mE}{2}+\frac{-\alpha+Km}{v}}
$$

Comment: add and subtract that pair of equations. Now you have $(x,r)=f(u,v)$ for a certain $f$. Plug this into $H$. (BTW you haven't defined $p_u,p_v$).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform correct, I did it. The problem is how can I express $p_{x}$ and $p_{y}$ in terms of $p_{u}$, $p_{v}$?

Comment: There is not a unique way. Any $(p_u,p_v)=F(p_x,p_y,x,y)$ is a good candidate.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I need to obtain the Hamilton-Jacobi equation in terms of these coordinates, and reduce it to quadratures. To do this I need to express H in terms of the new generalized momentum.

Comment: $y$ does not enter in your transformation; what is $r$ anyways.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I don't understant. $x=rcos(\theta)$, $y=rsin(\theta)$.

Comment: you have $u=r+x$, $v=r-x$.  There is no $y$ in this transformation.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero yes, the $y$ dependence is given by $r$. It is a problem from Goldstein. Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Is what's below what you have in mind?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero yes. Just when tou post it I was updating my results. Final expression does not look bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(up to typos and minor algebra errors)

1. Invert your transformation to get (up so the sign of $y$)
   $$
   x=\frac{u-v}{2}\, ,\qquad y=\sqrt{u v}\, .
   $$
2. Go back to the Lagrangian, which would be
   \begin{align}
   L&= \frac{m}{2}(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2)+\frac{k}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\, ,\\
   &= \frac{m}{2}\left(
   \frac{1}{4}(\dot{u}-\dot{v})^2
   +\frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{\dot{u}v}{\sqrt{u v}}+\frac{u\dot{v}}{\sqrt{u v}}\right)^2 \right)+\frac{2k}{\vert u+v\vert }
   \end{align}
3. Obtain the Hamiltonian using $H=p_u\dot u+p_v\dot v-L$, where
   $$
   p_u=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{u}}\, ,\qquad 
   p_v=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{v}}\, .
   $$

Comment: thank you very much. I have done some computations. The result is updated in the question.